# Angularjs How to access variables outside $on

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-events, broadcast

In one of my controllers I've defined this:

```
vm.searchTerm="12345";
vm.clickevent=function(){
  $rootScope.$broadcast('transferUp',{message:vm.searchTerm});
}
```

clickevent() is bound to a button in the view:

```
<button type="button" ui-sref="base.searchresults" data-ng-click="vm.clickevent()"></button>
```

in another controller I listen to the event:

```
vm.searchKeyword="";
$rootScope.$on('transferUp',function(event,data){
  vm.searchKeyword=data.message;
});
```

In the second controller when I try to `console.log(vm.searchKeyword)` outside `$on`, whitespace is logged. I think it has to do with variable scopes but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Its the normal behaviour, you get the value when you click on the button, so outside of the event `$on`, there is no value set. You have to think of this chunk of code to be executed outside of the normal flow of your controller. `$rootScope`.`$on(...)` will be executed only when you triggered the click.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

For any value changed inside an angular event `*.on()`, you need to use `$scope.$apply()` for the value to be updated in the scope.

```
vm.searchKeyword="";
$rootScope.$on('transferUp',function(event,data){
  vm.searchKeyword=data.message;
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: I have defined $on in $rootScope. should I use $rootscope.apply() or $scope.apply()?

Comment: $scope.$apply() will call a digest anyway. Stay with $rootscope.$apply()